# alternatives for tlsMinimumSupportedProtocolVersion in iOS 12

Tags: ssl, nsurlsession

My iOS library (a dynamic xcFramework) uses `URLSession` to perform some networking tasks. It targets iOS 13 and higher. I set

```
configuration.tlsMinimumSupportedProtocolVersion = tls_protocol_version_t.TLSv13
```

to mitigate *outdated TLS* attacks. So far so good.

But now I must support iOS 12 as a target, and there is no `tlsMinimumSupportedProtocolVersion` there. What would be the best approach for me?

Comment: Maybe [TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411526-tlsminimumsupportedprotocol) ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks, this should qualify as an answer (and will be accepted with deep appreciation).